# NodeJS - WITHOUT EXPRESS - how to get query-params?

Tags: node.js, req

I call my app by `localhost:3000?paramname=12345`

inside NodeJS I have

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('./app');

var server = http.createServer(app.handleRequest).listen(3000, function ()  {
    console.log('Server running on Port 3000');
});
```

and my app.js

```
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');

function handleRequest(req, res) {
    // parse url and extract URL path
    var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;  

    // file extention from url
    const ext = path.extname(pathname); 

    console.log(req.url); 

});
```

now the `console.log(req.url)` would output me `/?paramname=12345`

but how would i get only the var-name `paramname` or it's value `12345` ??

when I try everything i find, but I onl get `undefined` or the script brakes because no such function.

Comment: You need to parse the incoming request. Try something like body-parser

Comment: do I need explicit the `body-parser` ? or would it do `url.parse(req.url)` somehow , too?  .. i mean, i get  `paramname=12345` when I do `console.log(url.parse(req.url).query)`

Comment: I'm checking, but your app.js should export the handleRequest function using `module.exports`

Comment: oh, sorry, I have not copied it :) .. of course it exports the `handleRequest` as a module. so far it runs correctly until this one thing that i am not able to extract the query-varname or its value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`querystring`](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

...
const parsed = url.parse(req.url);
const query  = querystring.parse(parsed.query);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'url' moduele for getting query params in pure Nodejs (without express)
below are some code snippets-
[image: code snippet]

[image: request path]

Answer (score 0):

well if you really want to manually to do this, first you must know that the http request object is a stream of data, so what we can do is collect that stream chunks of data at the end, then join all streams of data together and then convert that to a readable data

```
else if (url == "/register" && req.method == "POST"){

const chunks = [];
const dataObj = {};
req.on("data",(chunk)=>{
    chunks.push(chunk); //push the chunks of data to chunk array
});

req.on("end",()=>{

    let data = Buffer.concat(chunks); //join all the received chunk to a buffer data
    data = data.toString(); //convert the buffer data to a readable data
    const parseData = new URLSearchParams(data); //using the the URLSearchParams we can convert the result data to a separate pairs of values and data
    for (let pair of parseData.entries()){

        dataObj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }
    console.log(`your first name is : `,dataObj.first_name, `and your last name is :` ,dataObj.last_name)

})

res.write("<h1>form was submitted</h1>");
return res.end();}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Node documentations](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#class-urlsearchparams) shows how. You have to create a new URL object first then the methods like `.searchParams.get('abc')` are available.

```
const myURL = new URL('https://example.org/?abc=123');
console.log(myURL.searchParams.get('abc'));
// Prints 123
```

Answer (score -1):

Per newest Node documentation, original answer give to this question is deprecated now.

You need to use following code to parse parameters provided to GET request.

```js
const parsedUrl = new URL(request.url, `http://${req.headers.host}`);
console.log(parsedUrl.searchParams.get('<parameter-name>'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).